# How do I put together a dataframe in R with webscraping if some data is missing?

Tags: html, r, dataframe, web-scraping

My project is to webscrape data from a webshop dealing in cars, using rvest in R. I look for each node, save it to a vector, then at the end I combine it into a dataframe. However not every car has all the variables filled and the dataframe is not getting created because "arguments imply differing number of rows: 24, 25". How should I solve this?

```
for (i in 2:2){
  cim <- paste("https://auto.jofogas.hu/magyarorszag/auto?o=", i, sep="")
  lap <- read_html(cim)

  brand <- html_nodes(lap, ".vehicle-brand") 
  brand <- html_text(brand)

  model <- html_nodes(lap, ".vehicle-model")
  model <- html_text(model)

  price <- html_nodes(lap, ".price")
  price <- html_text(price)
  price <- str_squish(price)
  price <- substr(price, 1, nchar(price)-3)
  price <- str_replace_all(price, " ", "")
  price <- as.numeric(price)
  price

  year <- html_nodes(lap, ".vehicle-reg-date")
  year <- html_text(year)
  #year <- as.Date(year)

  fuel <- html_nodes(lap, ".vehicle-fuel")
  fuel <- html_text(fuel)

  location <- html_nodes(lap, ".cityname")
  location <- html_text(location)

  autoJofogas <- data.frame(brand, model, price, year, fuel, location)
}
```

Because the page is getting refreshed with newer sales each minute, the result is not always reproducable, but as soon as someone uploads a sale without a certain variable, the result will be:

```
Error in data.frame(brand, model, price, year, fuel, location) : 
  arguments imply differing number of rows: 24, 25
```

Comment: As a workaround I used try-catch: since the website has about a 1000 pages, i decided to omit adding that given page's data which has missing data. It's not the greatest solution, because I'll be missing lots of data, but for my purpose it works. Still, if you have an idea to how to actually solve the issue, share it with us.

Comment: I found it best to try and see what is required to make a full row to my data, if it is missing then fill it with NA to ensure 25. I've not looked at your webpage to see if this would work for you.  As an aside, I noticed you're storing each element of the loop in the same variable name. It means you might be left with just the last iteration when completing the loop

Comment: You need to first parse out the parent node of the ".vehicle-brand" node.  This will provide a consist list of 25 nodes then parse each of these nodes with `html_node()` to find the details for each.  Similar problem here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54478175/rvest-return-nas-for-empty-nodes-given-multiple-listings/54482390#54482390